# Keep terminals open while changing folders

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh-keys

Sometimes I have to go through 30+ projects to make small change to each one and push changes to github repo. Right now I have setup my ssh command in `.bash_profile`, after entering command I just have to enter my SSH password. I didn't add password to file because I don't want to keep it on disk.(should I?)

Now problem is, every time I change folder, vscode kills and creates new terminal instance and I am forced to re-enter my ssh password. Is it possible to keep old terminal instances in vs code? Or any suggestions to improve my workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use [this terminals manager extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-terminals); it has support for persistent terminals, and easy config file to turn off autokill. A hacky solution I've used is just to pop out the terminal with the open ssh session into its' own window. It won't then be updated by anything else I do in vscode.